# Получить значение из формы html

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
  $shop_id = '399'; // ID проекта
  $secret_key = '...'; // Секретный ключ
  $pay_id = uniqid(); // Номер счета
  $currency = 'RUB'; // Валюта платежа
  $sign = md5($currency.':'.$amount.':'.$secret_key.':'.$shop_id.':'.$pay_id); 
?>

<select name="amount" class="form-control" required="">
                    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Выберите услугу</option>
                    <optgroup label='Игровая валюта'>
                        <option value="20.00">
                            10.000.000 печенек — 20 рублей
                        </option>
                        <option value="40.00">
                            20.000.000 печенек — 40 рублей
                        </option>
                        <option value="60.00">
                            30.000.000 печенек — 60 рублей
                        </option>
                        <option value="80.00">
                            40.000.000 печенек — 80 рублей
                        </option>
                    <optgroup label='Привелегии'>
                        <option value="50.00">
                            VIP — 50 рублей
                        </option>
                        <option value="100.00">
                            PREMIUM — 100 рублей
                        </option>
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
```

amount у меня вводиться в форме. Вопрос как мне тогда генерировать $sign в начале?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нет желания после выбора пользователем amount снова обращаться к серверному скрипту можно нагенерировать свой sign под каждый возможный amount и в зависимости от выбора подставлять (как понимаю перенаправлять на сторонний сайт)

Comment: Формирование подписи производится путем склеивания параметров через ":" и создание контрольной суммы MD5. Склеиваются параметры currency, amount, секретный ключ, merchant_id и pay_id.

По другому сервис не принимает

Comment: @Михаил, ну и ?  Генеришь каждый <option value="http://site.com?sign=<?md5($currency.':'.20.':'.$secret_key.':'.$shop_id.':'.$pay_id); ?"> 10.000.000 печенек — 20 рублей </option> и потом по событию onchange например перенаправляешь